# Displaying/Hidding chained CSS3 animations with jQuery on Mouseenter/Mouseleave

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-animations

I am playing a bit with [animate.css](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css) and jQuery on a bootstrap-based environment.
But I have a big problem!

I want to trigger animations on `mouseenter` / `mouseleave`, so I *chained* some complex set of callbacks, and now It's driving me crazy.

Look at my jQuery (no-conflict mode because of other plugins):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    var animationend = "webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend";
    var imgRotacion = "animated rotateOut";
    var h3Bounce = "animated bounceIn";
    var pFlip = "animated flipInX";
    var imgRotacionOff = "animated rotateIn";
    var h3BounceOff = "animated bounceOut";
    var pFlipOff = "animated flipOutX";


    jQuery(".procaption").on("mouseenter", function () {

        jQuery(this).find("img").addClass(imgRotacion).one(animationend, function () {
            jQuery(this).hide();
            jQuery(this).parent().find("h3").removeClass("hidden").addClass(h3Bounce).one(animationend, function () {
                jQuery(this).parent().find("p").removeClass("hidden").addClass(pFlip);
            });
        });
    });


    jQuery(".procaption").on("mouseleave", function () {
        jQuery(this).find("p").removeClass().addClass(pFlipOff).one(animationend, function () {
            jQuery(this).removeClass().addClass("hidden");
            jQuery(this).parent().find("h3").removeClass().addClass(h3BounceOff).one(animationend, function () {
                jQuery(this).removeClass().addClass("hidden");
                jQuery(this).parent().find("img").removeClass(imgRotacion).show().addClass(imgRotacionOff);
            });
        });
    });


});
```

The HTML is pretty simple:

```
<div class="procaption wow fadeInLeft well text-center">
      <img src="holder.js/150x150" alt="150x150" class="img-responsive img-circle center-block">

      <h3 class="hidden">This is a title</h3>

      <p class="hidden">But this is a description!</p>
</div>
```

**The behavior I want to achieve**:
Well, I want to chain all the animations, so they appear and disappear in some kind of order at `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events.

Actually, it's "working" but only when `mouseleave`is triggered after the last animation of `mouseenter` have happened.

If I try to `mouseenter`and instantly `mouseleave`, the `<p>But this is a description!</p>` line appears along with the `<img>`... That shouldn't happen!

**Here's the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Frondor/4koc4aaw/).**

I'm sure there should be some easier way, but I'm just learning and practicing... So any suggestion will be really appreciated!

Just for the record, I tried changing the `.procaption` with `.procaptioning`during the animation, until the last callback is complete, but didn't work :(
I also tried `$(".procaptioning").on("mouseenter mouseleave", function() { return false; })` ... without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.removeClass()` functions are messing with things since they are not targeting anything. Essentially, hovering on and off quickly will cause overlapping functions to create unexpected results without specifying which classes to remove at which times. I've also made the code clearer by reducing nested `this` usage and using consistent selectors. See this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tomanow/4koc4aaw/7/)** for working example.

```
function onHoverIn(e) {
    var $caption = jQuery(this),
        $image = $caption.find('img'),
        $h3 = $caption.find('h3'),
        $desc = $caption.find('p');

    $image.addClass(imgRotacion).one(animationend, function () {
        $image.addClass('hidden');
        $h3.removeClass('hidden').addClass(h3Bounce).one(animationend, function () {
            $desc.removeClass(pFlipOff + ' hidden').addClass(pFlip);
        });
    });
}

function onHoverOut(e) {
    var $caption = jQuery(this),
        $image = $caption.find('img'),
        $h3 = $caption.find('h3'),
        $desc = $caption.find('p');

    $desc.removeClass(pFlip).addClass(pFlipOff).one(animationend, function () {
        $desc.removeClass(pFlipOff).addClass('hidden');
        $h3.removeClass(h3Bounce).addClass(h3BounceOff).one(animationend, function () {
            $h3.removeClass(h3BounceOff).addClass('hidden');
            $image.removeClass(imgRotacion).removeClass('hidden').addClass(imgRotacionOff);
        });
    });
}

jQuery(".procaption").hover(onHoverIn, onHoverOut);
```

Comment: As far as I know, the `.removeClass()` is intended to remove ALL clases, so instead of `.removeClass(pFlipOff + ' hidden')` I was using `.removeClass()`. 
Anyway, you are using some kind of semantic really new for me, I didn't knew that you can declare variables in jQuery like that.. What's the difference? How should I google that? Is that pure javascript?
It works really nice man! Thanks a lot for your time! For real :)

Comment: My pleasure, glad it helped. I put a `$` before jQuery object variables just as convention, but they are just regular variables and you can of course omit the dollar sign if it looks weird haha.

Comment: Also, you are correct, `.removeClass()` removes all the classes assigned to the DOM element and just coincidentally happened to cause an issue but was not used incorrectly :)